# React: Getting Initial State in Class based compopnents

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a react-native, redux app, and after upgrading I've started getting some warnings about lifecycle hooks. My code looks like below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { selectPosts} from '../redux/selectors/postSelector';
import { getPosts } from '../redux/actions/postActions';

class BasicScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    myItems: [],
  };
  componentWillMount() {
    this.getPosts();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkforItems();
  }
  getPosts = async () => {
    // Call to a redux action
    await this.props.getPosts();
  };
  
  checkforItems = async () => {
    // myItems in initial state are set from data in 
    AsyncStorage.getItem('MyItems').then(item => {
      if (item) {
        this.setState({
          myItems: JSON.parse(item),
        });
      } else {
        console.log('No data.');
      }
    });
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // Data comes from the redux action.
    if (
      nextProps.data &&
      !this.state.data.length &&
      nextProps.data.length !== 0
    ) {
      this.setState({
        data: nextProps.data,
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>/* A detailed view */</View>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  data: selectPosts,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  dispatch,
  getPosts: () => dispatch(getPosts()),

});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BasicScreen);
```

To summarize, I was calling a redux action (this.getPosts()) from componentWillMount(), and then updating the state by props received in componentWillReceiveProps. Now both these are deprecated, and I am getting warnings that these are deprecated.

Apart from this, I am also setting some initial state by pulling some data from storage (this.checkforItems()). This gives me another warning - Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.

To me it looks like the solution lies in converting this into a functional component, however, I'm stuck at how I will call my initial redux action to set the initial state.

**UPDATE:**

I converted this into a functional component, and the code looks as follows:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

import { StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Text,
  Right,
} from 'native-base';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import {
  makeSelectPosts,
} from '../redux/selectors/postSelector';
import { getPosts } from '../redux/actions/postActions';

const BasicScreen = ({ data, getPosts }) => {

  const [myData, setData] = useState([]);
  const [myItems, setItems] = useState([]);

  const checkForItems = () => {
    var storageItems = AsyncStorage.getItem("MyItems").then((item) => {
      if (item) {
        return JSON.parse(item);
      }
    });
    setItems(storageItems);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getItems() {
      await getPosts(); // Redux action to get posts
      await checkForItems(); // calling function to get data from storage

      setData(data);
    }
    getItems();
  }, [data]);

    return (
      <View>
        <>
          <Text>{JSON.stringify(myItems)}</Text>
          <Text>{JSON.stringify(myData)}</Text>
        </>
      </View>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  data: makeSelectPosts,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  dispatch,
  getPosts: () => dispatch(getPosts()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BasicScreen);
```

It works, but the problem is that the first Text - {JSON.stringify(myItems)} - it is rerendering continuously. This data is actually got using checkForItems(). I wanted the useEffect to be called again only when the data updates, but instead something else is happening.

Also, I noticed that setData is not being called correctly. The data becomes available through the prop (data), but not from the state (myData). myData just returns empty array.

Comment: Have you tried moving the logic in `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount`, and `componentWillReceiveProps` to `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: I did try that and it solves the problem with redux action. But the second part about this.checkforItems(), still gives the error - Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component. So, I wanted to explore how I can convert this into a functional component.

Comment: `checkforItems` is clearly only setting its own state, are you *sure* this is the cause of that warning/error? If you want to convert to a functional component then `useState` hook replaces state and `useEffect` replaces `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount`. If you take a stab at converting and update your question, we can help if you get stuck in the conversion.

Comment: Ok, I will write the functional component. I am mostly clear that I will be able to dispatch the redux action from useEffect(). But how and where will I update the state when the props update? Currently I was doing it in componentWillReceiveProps.

Comment: Use an `useEffect` hook with *that* prop value in its dependency array. You can use as many hooks in a component as you need; you don't have to cram it all in a single hook.

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the question with a new functional component I created. But problem is that when I add the prop 'data' in the dependency array, the other function inside it keeps rerendering. I don't know how to stop that from happening.

Comment: `data` is a completely external value from props, so I think one of two things is occurring. (1) `getPosts` action updates redux store which updates the injected `data` prop and retriggers effect, or (2) as some indirect effect the parent is remounting `BasicScreen` and the effect is simply running because the component mounted. You can rule out remounting by testing with `useEffect(() => console.log('mounted'), [])` and you see only one log. What does `getPosts` action do?

Comment: getPosts()  does what you said, it updates the redux store which inturn updates the 'data' prop. Another problem is that setData() is not being called correctly. So, the data is available from the prop 'data' from not from the state myData.

Comment: If I have 'data' in the array dependency, it keeps mounting again and again. But if the dependency array is empty, then it mounts only once.

Comment: I can still do without having data in the dependency array. But I'm still not able to use setData() correctly.

Comment: Why are you duplicating redux state/props into local component state? This is actually an anti-pattern. You can simply just consume the prop when rendering, i.e. `<Text>{JSON.stringify(data)}</Text>`. I think the effect with empty dependency array for "onMount" to fetch posts and the other data from localStorage is fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll just do that. But I'm still unable to understand how I would do it if I had to.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... how to do what if you had to?

Comment: Sorry, I was just thinking if I had to duplicate the redux state/prop to local state, how I would do it from inside useEffect. But it's not necessary. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Yeah, you really just don't do that. Glad to assist. Cheers.